# OpenSearch Installation | securityadmin.sh | UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout

Tags: open-source, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

We installed OpenSearch on 4 VMs(1 coordinating node, 1 master node and 2 data nodes) and according to documentation https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/cluster/

when we login to OpenSearch URL or via curl, we are getting following msg:

e.g.
[apm@IR-APM-DEV-MN1 config]$  curl -XGET https:// :9200/_cat/plugins?v -u 'admin:admin' --insecure

**OpenSearch Security not initialized.**

According to it and msg we saw “**[opensearch-master] Not yet initialized (you may need to run securityadmin)**" , we executed securityadmin script as follows:

**./securityadmin.sh -cd ../securityconfig/ -nhnv    -cacert ../../../config/root-ca.pem    -cert ../../../config/kirk.pem    -key ../../../config/kirk-key.pem -h    -cn apm-cluster-1 -arc -diagnose**

And got following error msg for example:

Will update '_doc/config' with ../securityconfig/config.yml
FAIL: Configuration for 'config' failed because of **UnavailableShardsException[[.opendistro_security][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[.opendistro_security][0]] containing [index {[.opendistro_security][_doc][config], source[n/a, actual length: [3.7kb], max length: 2kb]}]** and a refresh]]
....

Can someone advise if any suggestions to overcome those errors?  (primary shard is not active Timeout / increase max length )

Thanks,
Noam

Answer (score 0):

simply we can disable the security method:

```
cd /path/to/opensearch-1.2.4

sudo nano config/opensearch.yml
```

Add the below line :-

```
plugins.security.disabled: true
```

If not try this link generate key and follow the given steps in the official.

> https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/install/tar/

Thank You.